# Merge two Imagemagick convert commands

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to Create a thumbnail from GIF 1st command and then merge another image on top of it 2nd command.

1st command:-
`convert -thumbnail 398x398 -auto-orient -quality 85 giphy.gif[0] output.jpg`

2nd command:- `convert -size 1920x1080 xc:none output.jpg -blur 5x4 -composite out1.png -gravity center -composite outfinal.png`

I've tried using like this but didn't work out:
`convert -thumbnail 398x398 -auto-orient -quality 85 giphy.gif[0] output.jpg | convert -size 398x398 xc:none  output.jpg -blur 5x4 -composite out1.png -gravity center -composite outfinal.png`

Image extracted from gif:- [image: image extracted from gif]

2nd image:[image: 2nd image]

Final output as merge two images :[image: Final out put]

Thank you:)

Comment: Please include your 2 starting images and another showing how it is supposed to end up because your commands are really mixed up and confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty easy way to do it:

```
convert -gravity center background.jpg -blur 5x4  \
    \( yinyang.png -resize 130x78\! \)            \
    -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

I put a spurious `-resize 130x78\!` in there so you can see where to do extra operations that only affect the little *"yin yang"* picture in the middle - you can obviously remove it.

Maybe I can explain the logic... the first line of the command deals with the background, the second line deals with the overlay. So, first, load up the background picture and make all the edits you want to it, i.e. blurring. Then start some *"aside-processing"* in parentheses which loads up the *"yin yang"* and applies some edits to that exclusively without affecting the background image. Then, when you are happy with the overlay, exit the parentheses and take the result of the *"aside-processing"* and overlay it on top of the background. It overlays into the centre because I set the gravity beforehand.

Hope that helps.

---

Added in response to your comment... if you want to do the extraction as well, just do that in the *"aside-processing"*:

```
convert -gravity center                                      \
   giphy.gif[0] -thumbnail 398x398 -auto-orient -blur 5x4    \
   \( yin yang -resize 300x100\! \)                          \
   -composite result.jpg
```

Comment: I guess you get it all wrong. There are two commands 1st one is to extract the image from gif image(Original) and 2nd command do the merging of those two images. Those two commands work perfectly for me. Now my question is how do I combine those 2 commands into single command i.e. extraction and merge of two images.

Comment: I have pushed the extraction into the single command for you - have another look please.

Comment: Again sorry for the miscommunication, the background.jpg I have to extract from giphy.gif and on the output of giphy.gif which will be background.jpg have load up the 'yin yan' image which is a separate image. Thank You.

Comment: Ok, hopefully we are getting there now! I have edited again.

Comment: Yup that works perfectly thank you so much for your time and help :)

Comment: No problems. Good luck with your project!